# How to use AMPscript lookup to show a users contact data for email personalisation?

Tags: ampscript, lookup

From what I understand I can use a lookup to show a users contact data rather than bringing into a static data extension, great for journeys where a users number of loyalty points might have changed for example.

However, is there a way to have the lookup value a 'current user'? so instead of the contact id 46016, it changes depending on the contact ID of the user being sent that email?

`%%=Lookup('Contact_Salesforce2','ActualLoyalty__pc','contact_id',46016)=%%`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the variable for your `ContactId` in AMPscript which matches the field in your sendable data extension. i.e.

```
%%[
set @contactId = [Id]
]%%
%%=Lookup('Contact_Salesforce2','ActualLoyalty__pc','Id',@contactId)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson! 

Am getting an error message when trying to lookup in a synchronised data extension? Do you know if this is possible?

The query works when using a standard data extension for the lookup.

Comment: Lookups work on synchronized DE's. I've edited my answer as you'll need to lookup on the `Id` field

Comment: Strange will try a few more times with different variables and see what happens!